# How to add an object into a square which is pre-defined in Python-3x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, graph-drawing

I drove a board with 8x8 dimension by using turtle module. It looks like a chessboard,but it is not,since the black blocks are randomly distributed.

The aim is that I want to make an A-Star Algorithm. The algorithm part is done. However, I am stuck in the graphical interface part.

I was using `turtle-graphics` module, but as far as I can understand, it draws the shapes by using a pen, which is move whole specific path by drawing the lines. I was dealing with the functions of turtle module in order to understand what are they.

My question are:

1. I want to put an object or image into a specific block. In fact, the block that I put into the object will be white.
2. I also want that object to move from one block to another block like a chess game. (However, it is not).
3. After one movement, is it possible to fill the previous block with a color ? (Actually, it is possible, I've done this part, but it was a bit time consuming. I mean, the program has to wait a bit to complete the pen movements in order to fill that block with a color.)

   ```py
   import turtle
   import image
   Tess=turtle.Turtle()
   Tess.pensize(1)
   Tess.speed(-100)
   w=40

   def mysquare(who,thecolor,size):
       who.pendown()
       who.pencolor('black')
       who.fillcolor(thecolor)
       who.begin_fill()
       who.setheading(0)
       for i in range(4):
           who.forward(size)
           who.left(90)
       who.end_fill()

   for j in range(8):
     for i in range(8):
   #      print(i,j)
         if i==5 and j==7 or i==5 and j==6 or i==3 and j==5 or i==7 and j==5 or i==2 and j==4 or i==4 and j==4 or i==5 and j==4 or i==6 and j==4:
             scolor='black'
         else:
             scolor='white'
         Tess.penup()
         Tess.goto((i-4)*w,(j-4)*w)
         mysquare(Tess,scolor,w)
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following exhibits the behaviors you describe.  It sets up the board, moves the turtle to a white square and then randomly moves it to squares it hasn't already visited (avoiding black squares) until it runs out of valid moves:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import choice

WIDTH = 40
BOARD_SIZE = 8
COLOR_EMPTY, COLOR_BLOCKED, COLOR_VISITED, COLOR_FAILED = 'white', 'black', 'green', 'red'

blocked_squares = [(5, 7), (5, 6), (3, 5), (7, 5), (2, 4), (4, 4), (5, 4), (6, 4)]  # should generate randomly

def mysquare(turtle, i, j, color, size):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto((i - BOARD_SIZE//2) * size, (j - BOARD_SIZE//2) * size)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.setheading(0)

    turtle.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

def board_to_screen(position):
    y, x = position
    return ((x - BOARD_SIZE//2) * WIDTH + WIDTH / 2, (y - BOARD_SIZE//2) * WIDTH + WIDTH / 2)

def move():
    global position

    positions = []

    for j_delta in (-1, 0, 1):
        if 0 <= position[0] + j_delta < BOARD_SIZE:
            for i_delta in (-1, 0, 1):
                if 0 <= position[1] + i_delta < BOARD_SIZE:
                    if board[position[0] + j_delta][position[1] + i_delta]:
                        new_position = (position[0] + j_delta, position[1] + i_delta)
                        if new_position != position:
                            positions.append(new_position)
    j, i = position

    if positions:
        board[j][i] = False
        mysquare(tess, i, j, COLOR_VISITED, WIDTH)
        position = choice(positions)
        screen.ontimer(move, 1000)
    else:
        mysquare(tess, i, j, COLOR_FAILED, WIDTH)

    tess.penup()
    tess.goto(board_to_screen(position))
    screen.update()

tess = Turtle(shape='turtle')
tess.speed('fastest')

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(0)

board = []

for j in range(BOARD_SIZE):
    board.append(list())
    for i in range(BOARD_SIZE):
        board[j].append(True)
        square_color = COLOR_EMPTY
        if (i, j) in blocked_squares:
            square_color = COLOR_BLOCKED
            board[j][-1] = False
        mysquare(tess, i, j, square_color, WIDTH)

screen.update()

position = (3, 3)
tess.penup()
tess.goto(board_to_screen(position))

screen.ontimer(move, 1000)

screen.exitonclick()
```

This is probably better done with multiple turtles to avoid some of the moves and the turtle on the board can be a GIF image instead of a built-in turtle shape.  The black squares should probably be generated randomly (but carefully) as should the initial starting position on the board of the turtle.

[image]